i got Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
C:\CodeServirAppDevelopment\New folder\globalstore\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:229: error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar (aka com.difmo.difeat:style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
how to solve this error

What did you do before having that error message?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
